# how to delete few rows of data from a text file using shell scripting based on some conditions

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sh

I have a text file with more than 100k rows. Below mentioned data is a sample for the text file I have. I want to use some conditions on this data and delete some rows. The text file does not have headers (ID,NAME,Code-1,code,2-code-3). I mentioned for reference. How can I achieve this with shell scripting?

Input test file:

```
| ID | NAME | Code-1 | code-2 | code-3 | 
| $$ | 5HF | 1E | N | Y | 
| $$ | 2MU | 3C | N | Y | 
| $$ | 32E | 3C | N | N | 
| AB | 3CH | 3C | N | N | 
| MK | A1M | AS | P | N | 
| $$ | Y01 | 01 | F | Y | 
| $$ | BG0 | 0G | F | N |
```

Conditions:

1. if code-2 = 'N' and code-1 not equal to ( '3C' , '3B' , '32' , '31' , '3D' ) then ID='$$'
2. if code-2 ='N' and code-1 equal to ( '3C' , '3B' , '32' , '31' , '3D') then accept any ID and (accept ID='$$' only if code-3='Y')'
3. if code-2 != 'N' then accept (ID='$$' only if code-3='Y') and all other IDs

Output:

```
| ID | NAME | Code-1 | code-2 | code-3 | 
| $$ | 5HF | 1E | N | Y | 
| $$ | 2MU | 3C | N | Y | 
| AB | 3CH | 3C | N | N | 
| MK | A1M | AS | P | N | 
| $$ | Y01 | 01 | F | Y |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @sunanda p - If _The text file does not have headers_, then don't misguide readers by inserting them in preformatted blocks.

Comment: _accept any ID and (accept ID='$$' only if code-3='Y')_ is contradictory.

Comment: I meant accept all other IDs and (accept ID='$$' only if code-3='Y')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's encouraged you demonstrate own efforts when ask questions. But I do understand this question could be complicated if you are new to Bash. Here is my solution using awk. Spent 0.545s processed 137k lines on my computer (with moderate specs).

```
awk '{
ID=$2; NAME=$4; CODE1=$6; CODE2=$8; CODE3=$10;
if (CODE2 == "N") {
  if (CODE1 ~ /(3C|3B|32|31|3D)/) {
    if (ID == "$$") {
      if (CODE3 == "Y") {
        print;
      }
    }
    else {
      print;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (ID == "$$") {
      print;
    }
  }
}
else {
  if (ID == "$$") {
    if (CODE3 == "Y") {
      print;
    }
  }
  else {
    print;
  }
}}' file
```

Note it has certain restrictions:

a) It delimits values by spaces not `|`. It will work with your exact input format, but won't work with input rows without additional spaces, e.g.

```
|$$|32E|3C|N|N|
|AB|3CH|3C|N|N|
```

b) For the same reason, the command will generate incorrect result, if col value has extra spaces, e.g.

```
| $$ | 32E FOO | 3C | N | N |
| AB | 3CH BBT | 3C | N | N |
```

Comment: After checking the conditions will this code delete the unwanted rows? I just want to know why we are using print

Comment: The code prints wanted rows, rather than remove unwanted ones.